# Access to S3 Buckets - how can I supply the public ip address subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have set up two S3 buckets (live & test) for a client.  I restricted access to them and set up two users, both restricted to only those buckets and then supplied access keys for them to access them.

That all works as expected but the client has come back saying that their MFT application requires the public ip address subnet for accessing the buckets.  My understanding is that Amazon S3 uses a range of public IP addresses, and the specific IP addresses can change over time.  So how can I supply this to them?  Should I:

1. Download the JSON file containing the IP address ranges used by AWS: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json.
2. Parse the JSON file to find the IP address ranges for the eu-west-1 region, and specifically for the Amazon S3 service.

Is that what they are wanting?  I've never had this request before and so I'm confused!  Thanks all.

Comment: It's probably better to ask them for clarity on what they want rather than ask Stack Overflow to guess what they want. At a guess, they're asking for a set of IP addresses (possibly a CIDR range, if applicable) so that they can add egress firewall rules to their application.

Comment: My understanding is that is what they want - but how can I give them those IP addresses if they can vary?  Should I just point them to that ip-ranges link from AWS?

Comment: That's what I would do, if they really must have the [IP addresses of S3](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-find-ip-address-ranges). And they'll need to keep their firewall list up to date. I don't know how frequently S3 changes this list of IPs. BTW this is all assuming that their app is not itself running in AWS. If it were, there are other solutions e.g. S3 endpoints in VPC.

Comment: The IP addresses from AWS is [updated often weekly](https://github.com/seligman/aws-ip-ranges), sometimes daily, sometimes more frequently than that.  For S3, this could mean opening up something like 280k IPs depending on the region.